# firebase functions integration with xero-node

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, xero-api

Attempting to create a firebase function that is triggered by some database or onRequest event that creates payments on Xero to better manage incoming invoices.

Not sure I understand how to run (if its possible) the xero-node library from firebase functions.

I have been messing around with the two and it doesn't seem to be as simple as initialising the object with the secret ID and calling functions like i would expect:

```
const xero = new XeroClient({
  clientId: '230823jff',
  clientSecret: 'sdfh39fhsdaf',
  redirectUris: [`http://localhost:3000/xero`],
  scopes: 'openid profile email accounting.transactions offline_access'.split(' '),
})

xero.accountingApi.getInvoices('tennetid093242')
```

It looks like I need to generate an Access key with the following (which expires in 12 minutes):

```
let consentUrl = await xero.buildConsentUrl()
res.redirect(consentUrl)
```

messing around with the api in postman and this flow feels like i'm making it more complicated than it should be.

Is there a way I can just initialise it with an admin scope or something and not have to worry about access keys...
Or should i use xero-node on the client side... (surely not)

There are expressjs versions with xero-node so would i just do the equivilent with firebase onrequest functions by making the redirectUri the address of another firebase function to get the session key?

---

Im getting somewhere slowly..

my firebase functions look like this:

```
const xero = new XeroClient({
  clientId: '123213123123',
  clientSecret: '123123123123',
  redirectUris: ['http://localhost:5001/example/us-central1/xeroAuthCode'],
  scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'accounting.transactions', 'accounting.settings', 'offline_access']
})

exports.xeroInit = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  let consentUrl = await xero.buildConsentUrl()
  res.redirect(consentUrl)
})

exports.xeroAuthCode = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  let tokenSet = await xero.apiCallback(req.url)
  console.log(tokenSet)
})
```

The idea is that I call xeroInit and the token gets sent to xeroAuth
which seems to work because console logging the req.url gives:

```
/?code=c5105f6ce943....230a23fsadf&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20accounting.transactions%20accounting.settings&session_state=tFC6G9Go_zBguCjIpy8-9gl6-9SWLTlUmY5CXMq49es.3c42d9ca9e53285596193bf423f791f3
```

But i get this error when trying to set it apiCallback

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'callbackParams' of undefined
```

Testing with a pure express app this works perfectly i expect this is a bug with the firebase functions emulator...

Because this worked with express i used express inside my firebase function and calling apiCallback with the request.url worked...
Ill update the answer when i get it working fully for others who want to use firebase and xero-node together.

Comment: Edited my answer I think you just need to redo -> await xero.initialize() It looks like same issue as https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node/issues/298

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big thanks to SerKnight who helped me get this working on firebase functions for future reference here is the configuration I got working.

**Some notes**

- Just calling `xero.initialize()` in a firebase function as a callback didn't work for what ever reason so I used express to handle initial setup.
- Once I have the refresh token in the database my connect function does the magic so I don't need to buildConsentUrl every time i want to do call a function.
- you could just keep using express to call your functions if you wanted to.

Ensure your firebase function url is put into the `OAuth 2.0 redirect URIs` on xeros myapps page in full as you see it in my example. `localhost if using firebase emulators`

```
const app = express()
app.use(cors())

let x_client_id = functions.config().xero.client_id
let x_client_sectet = functions.config().xero.client_secret

const xero = new XeroClient({
  clientId: x_client_id,
  clientSecret: x_client_sectet,
  redirectUris: ['http://localhost:5001/example/us-central1/xeroInit/callback'],
  scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'accounting.transactions', 'accounting.settings', 'offline_access'],
  httpTimeout: 3000,
  state: 123
})

const connect = () =>
  new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
    let snapshot = await db.ref('xero-config').once('value')
    let tokenSet = snapshot.val()
    try {
      xero.initialize()
      const newTokenSet = await xero.refreshWithRefreshToken(x_client_id, x_client_sectet, tokenSet.refresh_token)
      db.ref('xero-config').set(newTokenSet)
      xero.setTokenSet(newTokenSet)
      res()
    } catch (error) {
      rej(error)
    }
  })

app.get('/connect', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await connect()
    res.send('Connection established')
  } catch (error) {
    let consentUrl = await xero.buildConsentUrl()
    res.redirect(consentUrl)
  }
})
app.get('/callback', async (req, res) => {
  let TokenSet = await xero.apiCallback(req.url)
  db.ref('xero-config').set(TokenSet)
  res.send('Token updated ')
})
exports.xeroInit = functions.https.onRequest(app)

exports.xeroOrganisation = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  await connect() //Doesn't handle errors and will break if inactive for 60 days but you get the idea
  await xero.updateTenants()
  res.json(xero.tenants[0])
})
```

1. Call your connect function with `http://localhost:5001/example/us-central1/xeroInit/connect`
2. Ensure once redirected you got the `token updated` message
3. call your xeroOrganisation function to ensure everything it working (:

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:
Ah I think what you need to do is just initialize the client the second time using:

```
await xero.initialize()
```

This needs to be called to setup relevant openid-client on the XeroClient

buildConsentUrl also calls `await xero.initialize()` under the hood so since you called it in the initial thread it setup the client correctly. Due to firebase functions being siloed i think you just need to call the initialize() fn.

---

---

you will need to have a user for the Xero org you want to communicate with via API go through a whole OAuth2.0 flow to generate the access_token.

There is a great example app I recommend checking out that shows the whole flow: https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-node-oauth2-app/blob/master/src/app.ts#L172

---

Is your goal in facilitating many users to use your app to read write to their orgs? Or are you just trying to connect and automate stuff for a single org?

If you are trying to do the second, this video shows how you can just generate the initial access_token in REST client and plug that into your code flow to be continually refreshed. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zcf_64yreVI

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I have a dashboard for all company personell to view invoicing that need actioning but I only want one user to be able to post payments to xero. (single org automate some things to change firebase records with webhooks aswell etc..)

Comment: I have updated my question to represent my progress if you would take a look; I would very much appreciate it: @Serknight @

Comment: Initialising xero in the firebase callback function gave the same error.. added an answer with my findings and what i managed to get working so far. (: